# Excel formula for calculating average of 52 cells out of possible 104 where blank cells exist

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, average

I have a significant amount of rows of data showing earnings per week for over 104 weeks with various blank cells.

I am looking for a formula that would average only the latest 52 cells that have earnings in them.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . It would be best if you can add a sample of your data (especially the ranges your data is in) so the answers can be more tailored to your need

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to get the average of the last 52 non-blank cells in a range (the data is in Column `A`):
`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(ROW(A:A)>=LARGE(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A)),MIN(COUNT(A:A),52)),IF(A:A<>"",A:A))),"")`

*Note: This is an array formula. If you have a current version of Microsoft Office (Microsoft 365), then you can input the formula in the top-left-cell of the output range, then press ENTER (like with any regular formula) to confirm the formula.* But If you have older/other versions of Excel, you need to **press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to confirm the formula (Excel will insert curly brackets at the beginning and end of the formula for you. Manually inserting those will not make the formula an array formula.)